# Add a column to a polars LazyFrame based on a group-by aggregation of another column

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a LazyFrame of `time`, `symbols` and `mid_price`:

Example:

```
time                symbols             mid_price
datetime[ns]        str                 f64
2024-03-01 00:01:00 "PERP_SOL_USDT@…    126.1575
2024-03-01 00:01:00 "PERP_WAVES_USD…    2.71235
2024-03-01 00:01:00 "SOL_USDT@BINAN…    126.005
2024-03-01 00:01:00 "WAVES_USDT@BIN…    2.7085
2024-03-01 00:02:00 "PERP_SOL_USDT@…    126.3825
```

I want to perform some aggregations over the time dimension (ie: group by `symbol`):

```py
aggs = (
    df
        .group_by('symbols')
        .agg([
            pl.col('mid_price').diff(1).alias("change"),
        ])
)
```

I get back a `list` of each value per unique `symbols` value:

```
>>> aggs.head().collect()

symbols             change
str                 list[f64]
"SOL_USDT@BINAN…    [null, 0.25, … -0.55]
"PERP_SOL_USDT@…    [null, 0.225, … -0.605]
"WAVES_USDT@BIN…    [null, -0.002, … -0.001]
"PERP_WAVES_USD…    [null, -0.00255, … 0.0001]
```

I would now like to join this back onto my original dataframe:

```py
df = df.join(
    aggs,
    on='symbols',
    how='left',
)
```

This now results in each row getting the full list of `change`, rather then the respective value.

```
>>> df.head().collect()

time                symbols             mid_price   change
datetime[ns]        str                 f64         list[f64]
2024-03-01 00:01:00 "PERP_SOL_USDT@…    126.1575    [null, 0.225, … -0.605]
2024-03-01 00:01:00 "PERP_WAVES_USD…    2.71235     [null, -0.00255, … 0.0001]
2024-03-01 00:01:00 "SOL_USDT@BINAN…    126.005     [null, 0.25, … -0.55]
2024-03-01 00:01:00 "WAVES_USDT@BIN…    2.7085      [null, -0.002, … -0.001]
2024-03-01 00:02:00 "PERP_SOL_USDT@…    126.3825    [null, 0.225, … -0.605]
```

I have 2 questions please:

1. How do I *unstack/explode* the lists returned from my `group_by` when joining them back into the original dataframe?
2. Is this the recommended way to add a new column to my original dataframe from a `group_by` (that is: `group_by` followed by `join`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to actually aggregate anything (and get a *single* value per symbol), but instead want to compute `"change"` but independently for each symbol.

In polars, this kind of behaviour, similar to [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) in PostgreSQL, can be achieved with [`pl.Expr.over`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html).

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("mid_price").diff(1).over("symbol").alias("change")
)
```

On some example data, the resolt looks as follows.

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "symbol": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 3,
    "time": [datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 1, hour) for hour in range(3)] * 3,
    "mid_price": np.random.randn(9),
})

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("mid_price").diff(1).over("symbol").alias("change")
)
```

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ symbol ┆ time                ┆ mid_price ┆ change    │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ A      ┆ 2024-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ -0.349863 ┆ null      │
│ A      ┆ 2024-03-01 01:00:00 ┆ 0.093732  ┆ 0.443595  │
│ A      ┆ 2024-03-01 02:00:00 ┆ -1.262064 ┆ -1.355796 │
│ B      ┆ 2024-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1.953929  ┆ null      │
│ B      ┆ 2024-03-01 01:00:00 ┆ 0.637582  ┆ -1.316348 │
│ B      ┆ 2024-03-01 02:00:00 ┆ 1.009401  ┆ 0.37182   │
│ C      ┆ 2024-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0.75864   ┆ null      │
│ C      ┆ 2024-03-01 01:00:00 ┆ -0.866227 ┆ -1.624867 │
│ C      ┆ 2024-03-01 02:00:00 ┆ -0.674938 ┆ 0.191289  │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Ha, thank you! Yes indeed, this is what I'm looking for - thank you for correcting me - definitely still learning all things polars! In my data `time` will be sorted, so if I call `over` over `symbols`, I presume I'm guranteed it will be done in the order of the rows, which is implicitly over time (struggling somewhat with the lack of the pandas index concept!)

Comment: @SteveLorimer Glad it helped! And yes - you are right in assuming the order will be maintained.